# How do I remove dependencies from a deb installer for an isolated system?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, application-development, dependencies, deb

I have created a deb package for an application created in Qt. I have included all the libraries that the application depends on, to be installed in a folder next to the application itself:

```
/usr/share/MyCompany/MyProduct/executable
/usr/share/MyCompany/MyProduct/Frameworks
```

Then exported `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to the `Frameworks` directory.

All perfect... Until I had to add QT Assistant, which requires additional libraries.

After checking the dependencies for Qt Assistant, I added all the required libraries, including `libQtHelp.so.4` and `libQtWebKit.so.4`, in the same directory.

My deb is very simple, I create the structure desired then set the "install" to copy my files to the target directories.

```
blah_1/* /usr/share/MyCompany/MyProduct/
```

To create the package, I create the tar then

```
dh_make --copyright gpl -f ../blah-1.0.tar.gz 
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -me@mycompany.com
```

When running the installer on a clean (no Qt) system, I am getting dependency errors:

```
me:~$ sudo dpkg -i /path/blah_1.0-1_i386.deb 

Selecting previously unselected package blah.
(Reading database ... 141841 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking blah (from .../blah_1.0-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of blah:
 blah depends on libqt4-help (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqt4-help is not installed.
 blah depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
  Package libqtwebkit4 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing blah (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blah
```

Unfortunately the system I am installing doesn't have (and will not have) internet access. How can I provide the packages required, in the same deb installer ?

Or, how can I disable checking for dependencies, since I am providing the required libs ?

(Ubuntu 12.04 if that is relevant)

**Update:** I ran

```
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libqt4-help,libqtwebkit4 /path/blah_1.0-1_i386.deb
```

The program installed correctly and ran perfectly.

Inside the package, in the `/DEBIAN/control`, i see listed the unwanted dependencies.

After calling dh_make I had no dependencies in the control file.

The dpkg-buildpackage must have placed the dependencies after checking (likely for assistant).

Can I remove them somehow ? Can I put a flag somewhere not to include dependencies ?

Or... still.... can I add in my packaging thing the deb packages and is there a command I can give to pre-install as part of the package installation ?

If there is no solution.... I suppose I can provide a script to run the dpkg command as above, with ignore-depends, but then he package cannot be installed from the Software Center...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: None of the 19 answers in the suggested question has anything to do with package creation, they all require users to install additional software - which I could provide but then it defeats the purpose of having a deb package hat includes all the dependencies. I am trying to REMOVE dependencies not to ADD MORE

Answer (score 0):

According to [`man dpkg-source`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-source.1.html):

```
-Dfield=value
      Override or add an output control file field.
```

And from [`man dpkg-buildpackage`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html):

```
--source-option=opt
      Pass option opt to dpkg-source.
```

So perhaps you could override the `Depends` field thus:

```
dpkg-buildpackage --source-option='-DDepends=...' ...
```

Comment: @Thalia I might be wrong in the syntax (it could be `--source-option='DDepends=...'` or something similar).

Comment: I also tried --source-option='UDepends' with no effect